# emacs package for working with tagged regions?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to be able to apply tags to regions of code and text and to be able to use these to narrow visibility to navigate - ideally across multiple files. So for example if I was researching C16th European history I could tag insert  and  and zoom around around cromwellish stuff quickly, limit my searches to cromwellish regions, etc. It's important that tags pairs shouldn't have to be "well-formed" because I might want to start an  region inside of a  but end  first. And, obviously, I'd to be able to list all my tags, and to search or narrow on combinations of them.

I can't find anything like this. Org-mode comes closest, but its tags are headline based, which makes stopping one tag while continuing other painful - plus I need headlines as headlines, and I'd like to be able to tag code this way too.

Is there anything like this? Or any toolkit that would be a good start to write this?

Comment: I have almost no idea what you are asking for (and suspect you were down-voted for the same reason). I recommend that you clarify what you mean and how it ought to work in practice (including some clear examples).

Comment: Realistically, the purpose of a question is to communicate with people who might be able to answer it. If you don't understand what applying a tag to a region means and want to, then go and look at the example I gave - ie Org Mode. Avnyone who can give me a useful answer will understand what a tag is, what a region is, and what applying a tag to a region means.

Answer (score 1):

Library [**Bookmark+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/BookmarkPlus) provides what you are asking for, I think. It enhances standard Emacs bookmarking in several ways, including some that respond to your request.

You can bookmark locations of all sorts, and the recorded bookmark information can include the [***region***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkedRegion) limits/context. (If the region is active when you set the bookmark then the region info is recorded.)

When you jump to the bookmark, the region is re-activated (if the region was recorded).
If the content of the destination file (or whatever) has been modified since the bookmark was last updated, so that the text around the recorded region has changed, the bookmark and region are automatically relocated (assuming that the new destination and limits are recognizable and thus locatable).

**Bookmark+** also lets you [***tag***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/BookmarkPlus#BookmarkTags) any bookmark (or file), in multiple ways.  Tags are arbitrary, free-form strings (but you can also optionally associate arbitrary Lisp values with them.)

And you can list all tags, search and narrow on tag combinations (unions, intersections, etc.). Tags are one of the most important **Bookmark+** features.

Library [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles) provides additional [enhancements](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles_-_Bookmark_Enhancements) regarding the use of **Bookmark+** bookmarks and tags.

Comment: Thanks - Bookmark+ is definitely a real possibility and the first I've heard of.